# MVN install, cannot find artifact in local repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

I did `mvn install` and get this error message 
`Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve dependencies for project test:core:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact lib-net:lib-net:jar:1.0.8 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

this dependency is a Project of mine, which is available in the local repository ~/.m2

so I tried `mvn install -o` to force maven to use my local repository, and I get this

`Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve dependencies for project test:core:jar:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The repository system is offline but the artifact lib-net:lib-net:jar:1.0.8 is not available in the local repository.`

I tried to delete my local repository and install everything again, but it doesn't solve my problem!

Any sugestions?

Comment: Did you define your local repository in pom file?

Comment: like here for an example - https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/

Comment: no, I use the default location ~/.m2/repository

Comment: Sound's like you have problem with file system structure. For an example you should have: com/user2071938/lib-net/1.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/[something with maven metadata files]. I had same problem in the past, and It was possible to resolve it only after I do "clean install" on maven project with type "jar". After it maven pack my project properly and I was able to use it in other projects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with maven version. I had the same issue on my Jenkins machine. I followed these steps and it resolved my issue:

1. Delete the specific older libraries in ~/.m2/
2. Change the version of maven to apache-maven-3.5.0
3. Re-run the maven goals

Answer (score 0):

Think I know way how to do it properly

1. Download sources of your library locally
2. Go to ~/.m2/ and search for your lib
3. Delete it from here
4. perform "mvn clean install" for your library
5. search for your lib in ~/.m2/
6. try to "mvn clean install" on your main project
7. ... ?
8. Profit

If it will no work, check that you use correct artifact id and group id.